# Like button for different pages

Tags: php, facebook

How to make facebook like button for different pages, I get button for site.com and i'm in

`site.compage?product=1` - page and if somebody like the thing on that page, it will output to the post page in facebook that the person liked site.com, how to make that way so if user likes some page to show the current page not the page that I added in the like button generator, so if user is on

`site.com/page?product=2` and hit the like button , I want on his facebook page to have that he liked `site.com/page?product=2` so every page on the site where is the button I want to be like that.

Comment: What happens when you put your URLs through the Facebook URL Linter? http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/ Do you see the appropriate product information, or just your generic page information? If it's generic, it seems like you're not outputting custom meta tags for each of the products. Look at the 'Open Graph Tags' section here (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Use [this jQuery plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-one-fblike/) which makes it as easy as

```
jQuery('#fb-like').onefblike();
```

Comment: It gives me error

Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'obefblike'

Comment: That plugin is very odd. It adds in meta tags with Javascript, but the crawler Facebook users to scrape the page information wouldn't see those. It's trying to fix (and not doing well) a problem that doesn't even exist. Like buttons are easy to implement if you follow the docs, but missing out a little key tag could be crucial.

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this... (along with the proper meta tags)

```
$url = "mysite/" . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
< iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/widgets/like.php?href=' . $url . >
```

Comment: It gives me product not found

Comment: when i click on the like button, it gives me that

Answer (score 0):

You're a little confusing to be honest, do you mean the title of the page is what you want to appear in the Like?

Make sure you have this in your main HTML tag:

```
xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"
```

Go to your HEAD section and put in something like this:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $function_to_get_title; ?>" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="site.com" />
```

If it's saying page not found or if FB is throwing up an error then check the link in the iFrame, use PHP:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php echo curPageURL(); ?>
```